# PrecedenceForm with Format

Tags: formatting, precedence

I'd like to format the output of certain operators with `Infix`-style formatting to have lower precedence than `Times`.

Let's say I define `foo` to format as `CenterDot` :

```
Format[x_foo]:=CenterDot@@foo
```

The following prints with no parentheses (as expected) :

```
a * foo[x,y]
(* a x \[CenterDot] y *)
```

This is the sort of output I want :

```
a*PrecedenceForm[ foo[x,y], 395 ]
(* a (x \[CenterDot] y) *)
```

However, I'd like to abstract this away a bit more.  I'd like to instead do something like

```
Format[x_foo]:=PrecedenceForm[CenterDot @@ x, 395]
```

so that this is handled entirely at the output level.  However, the `PrecedenceForm` doesn't seem to do anything:

```
a*foo[x,y]
(* a x \[CenterDot] y *)
```

Of course, I'm just as interested in why this doesn't work as I am in solving the problem of inserting parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

\I would suggest to use lower level formatting commands like this

```
MakeBoxes[foo[arg1_Symbol, arg2_Symbol], StandardForm] := 
 With[{arg1b = MakeBoxes[arg1], arg2b = MakeBoxes[arg2]},
  TemplateBox[{arg1, arg2}, "foo", 
   DisplayFunction :> (RowBox[{"(", 
        RowBox[{arg1b, "\[CenterDot]", arg2b}], ")"}] &)]]
```

> a (x \[CenterDot] y)

Using TemplateBox approach will allow you to convert output into desired input form. If you need only to output, just explicitly form the boxes.

You can add conditions as well, for example, the special formatting will occur only if first argument of bar is 1

```
MakeBoxes[bar[a__, foo[arg1_Symbol, arg2_Symbol]], StandardForm] :=

 With[{replBox = 
     RowBox[{"(", 
       RowBox[{MakeBoxes[arg1], "\[CenterDot]", MakeBoxes[arg2]}], 
       ")"}]},
   RowBox[{MakeBoxes[bar], "[", MakeBoxes[a], ",",replBox, "]"}]] /; 
  First[{a}] === 1


bar[1, foo[x, y]]
```

> bar[1, (x\[CenterDot]y)]

Comment: This is good, but I'd really like the parentheses to show up only under certain conditions.  Let's say I want the parentheses when `foo[...]` appears as the first argument of some head `bar` which satisfies some condition `conditionQ[bar]`.  Then I can imagine I'd do something like `MakeBoxes[bar_?conditionQ[a__, foo[arg1_Symbol, arg2_Symbol]], 
  StandardForm] := ???` -- what would go on the right hand side?  I'm unsure how to include the existing formatting of `bar` and its other arguments within MakeBoxes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`SyntaxForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxForm). For example:

```
foo /: MakeBoxes[foo[x,y], StandardForm] := TemplateBox[
    {MakeBoxes[x], MakeBoxes[y]},
    "foo",
    DisplayFunction->(RowBox[{#1, "\[CenterDot]", #2}]&),
    SyntaxForm->Star
]
```

I used [`Star`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Star) for the [`SyntaxForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxForm) since its precedence is 390, as requested, in between the precedences for [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) and [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times):

```
Precedence /@ {Plus, Star, Times}
```

> {310., 390., 400.}

Then:

```
a + foo[x, y]
a * foo[x, y]
```

[image]